# Using lodash's fp functions in a flow

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Having read that the `_.chain` method is "[considered harmful](https://medium.com/making-internets/why-using-chain-is-a-mistake-9bc1f80d51ba)" I thought I should attempt some flow instead. However, I'm running into an issue using the fp methods.

I've added a small example to [a repl](https://repl.it/@chooban/LodashTruncatePlaceholderWot) and reproduced the code below as well.

```
const flow = require('lodash/fp/flow');
const truncate = require('lodash/fp/truncate');
const mapValues = require('lodash/fp/mapValues');
const { inspect, format } = require('util');

const input = {
    firstField: 'I am a fairly long string so I want to be truncated',
    secondField: {
        foo: 'bar',
        bar: 'baz',
        baz: 'boo',
        boo: 'hoo',
        hoo: 'boy',
        boy: 'howdy'
    }
};

const doTheThing = data =>
    flow(
        mapValues(inspect), 
        mapValues(s => s.replace(/\s*\n\s*/g, ' ')),
        mapValues(truncate)
    )(data);

console.log(doTheThing(input));
```

When I run this, `truncate` isn't invoked how I expect it to be, and for output I get

```
{ firstField: { [Function: wrapper] placeholder: {} },
  secondField: { [Function: wrapper] placeholder: {} } }
```

I'm expecting to get back two truncated strings, not functions that have been toString'd. To get that, I have to change it to `mapValues(s => truncate(s)(s))`. This looks wrong to say the least, so have I wrongly combined flow and fp methods, or am I using them wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using them wrong. First of all with ordinary Lodash the [`truncate`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#truncate) function takes two parameters:

> _.truncate([string=''], [options={}])

where the second one is:

> [options={}] (Object): The options object.

With Lodash fp [there are no optional arguments](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#no-optional-arguments) and [some functions' arguments are rearranged](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide#rearranged-arguments) to make composition easier. So in fp `truncate` takes two parameters, first of which is the `options` object. To truncate a string with fp you need to provide two parameters:

```js
const truncFn = _.truncate({ length: 20 }); // is a function
const truncatedString = truncFn('I am a fairly long string so I want to be truncated'); // only this results in truncated string

console.log(truncatedString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.fp.min.js"></script>
```

Your snippet, fixed version ([repl link](https://repl.it/repls/HonorableKnowingContent)):

```
const flow = require('lodash/fp/flow');
const truncate = require('lodash/fp/truncate');
const mapValues = require('lodash/fp/mapValues');
const { inspect, format } = require('util');

const input = {
    firstField: 'I am a fairly long string so I want to be truncated',
    secondField: {
        foo: 'bar',
        bar: 'baz',
        baz: 'boo',
        boo: 'hoo',
        hoo: 'boy',
        boy: 'howdy'
    }
};

const doTheThing = data =>
    flow(
        mapValues(inspect), 
        mapValues(s => s.replace(/\s*\n\s*/g, ' ')),
        mapValues(truncate({})) // <--- FIX
    )(data);

console.log(doTheThing(input));
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much for the detailed answer.